# Why is SQL Server 2017 not recognizing AT Time zone?

Tags: timezone, sql-server-2017

I'm running the following query on a SQL server 2017 Database (developer edition). the query executes but it only shows the getdate value without actually converting. I also see that "AT TIME ZONE" is no fully highlighted in blue by the SQL editor, which  means it is probably not recognized. Any idea please?

```
SELECT 
    GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time' as CET,
    GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Cuba Standard Time' as 'Cuba Time'
```

P.S: I checked that time zones are defined and spelled correctly

```
SELECT * FROM sys.time_zone_info
```

Comment: Your Title *implies* that your getting an error (that `AT TIME ZONE` isn't valid syntax), not that you're getting unexpected behaviour

Comment: What is wrong with the output you get? For myself (who is located in a GMT timezone) I get the value `2020-01-17 14:22:18.697 +01:00` for `CET`; this is what I expect as as the time I ran the SQL *was* `14:22:18.697` locally.

Comment: It should give me a syntax error but for some reason, it doesn't. it just returns the current getdate() in CST when I've asked for CET. Also the the same output for both CET and Cuba doesn't make sense.

Comment: So, let's say you had the datetime `2020-01-17T15:48:27.123` (local time zone is irrelevant here) instead of `GETDATE()`, what would you expect to see with for CET? I would expect to see `2020-01-17 15:48:27.123+01:00`

Comment: Ok, I've tried your suggestion and I get the same output you expect. but because I am in CET time zone myslef, I tried a different time zone 
SELECT 
   cast( '2020-01-17 15:48:27.123' as datetime) AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' as 'Pacific time'
    and the output is still 2020-01-17 15:48:27.123 -08:00. how do I get it to actually apply the - 08:00 at the end? thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, so I don't see the problem; the function is working exactly as it should be. So what's the issue? In one breath you tell us it doesn't work (errors) and in another than it functions, but doesn't change the result, but now you've just said it *is* working. Therefore what *is* the problem...

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen that the time difference was appended at the end of the returned datetime at first. The question I have now is, looking at the Pacific time example, how do I  get the output to be directly  "2020-01-17 07:48:27.123" instead of "2020-01-17 15:48:27.123 -08:00"

Comment: @Saphiros - you wouldn't.  The offset indicates how much away from UTC the local time already is.  If you wanted to get the equivalent UTC time, you would subtract the offset, not add it.  In other words, `2020-01-17 15:48:27.123 -08:00` is the same as `2020-01-17 23:48:27.123 (UTC)`.  But if you're just looking for getting the current time in UTC, you don't need `AT TIME ZONE` at all.  What are you actually trying to do?  Get the current UTC time? Apply a time zone offset to a specific datetime? Or convert a specific datetime from one time zone to another? These are all different things.

Comment: Thank you all, I think I found a way to achieve what I need. I'll try to apply the time zone offset using the DateAdd function to get the exact time at the desired timezone. This is for an application where the business need to view all timestamps in CET format.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem is your misunderstanding of how `AT TIME ZONE` works with a `datetime` datatype (which is what `GETDATE()` returns). Take the following:

```sql
DECLARE @DT datetime = '2020-01-17T16:39:01.123';

SELECT @DT AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time' as CET,
       @DT AT TIME ZONE 'Cuba Standard Time' as [Cuba Time];
```

This returns the below:

```
CET                                Cuba Time
---------------------------------- ----------------------------------
2020-01-17 16:39:01.123 +01:00     2020-01-17 16:39:01.123 -05:00
```

Notice the times are the same as what is was in `@DT` *apart* from the timezone. This is because `datetime` is timezone agnostic; it doesn't know that exist. As a result the timezone is simply "added on" to the value.

If you use a `datetimeoffset`, however, you get the result you expect:

```sql
DECLARE @DT datetimeoffset(0) = '2020-01-17T16:39:01.123';

SELECT @DT AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time' as CET,
       @DT AT TIME ZONE 'Cuba Standard Time' as [Cuba Time];
```

Returns:

```
CET                                Cuba Time
---------------------------------- ----------------------------------
2020-01-17 17:39:01 +01:00         2020-01-17 11:39:01 -05:00
```

In your case, that means instead you need to use `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET`:

```sql
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time' as CET,
       SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Cuba Standard Time' as [Cuba Time];
```

For me, as I write this answer, that returns the below:

```
CET                                Cuba Time
---------------------------------- ----------------------------------
2020-01-17 17:43:55.5596303 +01:00 2020-01-17 11:43:55.5596303 -05:00
```